# Extract field in json with condition

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract the name of the city from a google maps API requests.
Here is the result of the request:

```
[{'long_name': 'Chandigarh',
  'short_name': 'Chandigarh',
  'types': ['locality', 'political']},
 {'long_name': 'Chandigarh',
  'short_name': 'CH',
  'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'India', 'short_name': 'IN', 'types': ['country', 'political']},
 {'long_name': '160022', 'short_name': '160022', 'types': ['postal_code']}]
```

I want to extract the name of the city knowing that it is not always the 1st one:

```
    print(x['long_name'][0] for x in geocode_result[0].get('address_components') if x.get('types')[0]=='locality')
```

But this give me a generator:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000021FB038F3B8>
```

However when I do a for loop, its ok:

```
for x in geocode_result[0].get('address_components'):
if x.get('types')[0]=='locality':
    print(x.get('long_name'))
Chandigarh
```

Do you see what is the problem in the one liner?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensions return a generator unless surrounded in `[]`, so just add those characters:

```
print([x['long_name'][0] for x in geocode_result[0].get('address_components') if x.get('types')[0]=='locality'])
```